# Getting difference in time_t

Tags: c++

I compute a start time like so ...

```
time_t test = (int)difftime(time(0), gStatStartTime);
struct tm tempinfo;             
localtime_s(&tempinfo, &test);              
char buffer2[80];
strftime(buffer2, 80, "[%H:%M:%S]", &tempinfo);

time(&gStatStartTime);
```

When I compute a "stop" time for a 1-second run, however, my program prints `[19:00:01]`.  The seconds value is correct, but the 19 hours is terribly wrong.  What could be the problem?

Comment: `localtime` and `strftime` format a time (and/or date), not a time *interval*. I don't think there are any functions in the standard library suitable for formatting a time interval, but you can surely find libraries online, or do it yourself (it's not hard if you're only going up to hours, just division with remainders).

Comment: I'm using boost as well, is there a function in there that you know of off the top of your head?

Comment: @Casper7526: Boost uses `boost::chrono` for most things, I have no idea if it can interop with `time_t` at all.  It probably can.

Comment: There probably is something (boost has everything and the kitchen sink), but I don't know it, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gmtime_s()` instead of `localtime_s()`

Comment: That's cheating... but it probably works just fine up to 23:59:59.

Comment: Well... since it would never run for 24 hours, this is what I'm going to use, though I know it's not really the "correct" answer haha, it works for me :)

Comment: @hobbs : IMHO it is a perfectly fine trick : a delta is seen by gmtime as a number of seconds after 1970-01-01 00:00:00 . As January is 31 days long, you can use the trick up to 31 days. (Of course fields year and month are of little if any interest ...)